# Referencing a project in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC that gets files submitted to it through the user interface which are then saved in a folder. I also have a separate project that I made a while back that takes a folder, converts the files inside of it and then saves the converted ones to a new folder.
I can't work out how to connect the project to the MVC so that I can call the folder conversion method from the user interface in the MVC.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, calling external executables from a web app is to be avoided. Can you instead place the relevant business logic inside of a class library, and then reference that class library from both projects? That way your web application can do what it needs to without calling external excutables.

Comment: do i need to save the class library as a .dll? if so i cant seem to work out how to do that

Comment: Simply compiling the app will save it as a DLL. But generally we don't directly reference DLL's. If you want all the projects in the same solution, then you add a reference to the project. If you want to have them separate, then you package up your DLL into a NuGet package and then add a reference to the NuGet package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile a separate application to convert the files in the folder, such as a console application, and run it on a scheduler such as Windows Task Scheduler. It can be completely independent of the MVC application.